# 2 click to copy buttons only copy 1 input field

Tags: javascript, button, input, onclick, copy

I have a working button that copies the text value from one input field.

I need to make two of these, but when I change the value, the first button starts copying the value from the first input-field. Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
function CopyCode(){
    var text = document.getElementById("input-text");
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
   }
var text = document.getElementById("element-id");
text.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
</script>

<input type="text" placeholder="CODE" value="CODE" style="text-align:center;" id="input-text"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">    
 $('input').keypress(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
  });

   </script>
   <button onclick="CopyCode()">COPY</button>  <br/> <br/>


            <!--- SECOND --->


<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
function CopyCode(){
    var text = document.getElementById("coupon2-text");
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
   }
var text = document.getElementById("element-id");
text.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
</script>

<input type="text" placeholder="CODE2" value="CODE2" style="text-align:center;" id="coupon2-text"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">    
 $('input').keypress(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
  });

   </script>
   <button onclick="CopyCode()">COPY</button>  <br/> <br/>
```

Tryit Editor: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWJF0IFLP9D8
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is the output of your current code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
function CopyCode(){
    var text = document.getElementById("input-text");
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
   }
var text = document.getElementById("element-id");
text.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
</script>

<input type="text" placeholder="CODE" value="CODE" style="text-align:center;" id="input-text"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">    
 $('input').keypress(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
  });

   </script>
   <button onclick="CopyCode()">COPY</button>  <br/> <br/>


            <!--- SECOND --->


<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
function CopyCode(){
    var text = document.getElementById("coupon2-text");
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
   }
var text = document.getElementById("element-id");
text.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
</script>

<input type="text" placeholder="CODE" value="CODE" style="text-align:center;" id="coupon2-text"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">    
 $('input').keypress(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
  });

   </script>
   <button onclick="CopyCode()">COPY</button>  <br/> <br/>
```

Here is the output of the updated code:

```js
function CopyCode(){
    var text = document.getElementById("coupon2-text");
    text.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
$("button").click(function() {
  var textId = $(this).attr("class");
  var text = document.getElementById(textId);
  text.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
});

$('input').keypress(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="CODE" value="CODE 1" style="text-align:center;" id="coupon2-text"/>
<button class="coupon2-text">COPY</button>  <br/> <br/>

<input type="text" placeholder="CODE" value="CODE 2" style="text-align:center;" id="input-text"/>
   <button class="input-text">COPY</button>  <br/> <br/>
```

Comment: Thank you Sami, but the values need to be different in each box. So for example. box one says and copies something different than box two. Can that be done?

Comment: Yes, that can be done. I have updated the values of the input in the snippet and now, you can see the text copies according to your need.

As i am getting the class name of the button which is actually the id of the input attribute so, works perfectly in your situation.